# How to use static ip address for Firebase to connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, networking, google-cloud-functions

How to use static ip address for Firebase to connect to MongoDB

Hello,

I'm using a Flutter/Firebase project, and for some reasons I need to also user MongoDB.

I saw that you can only authorize some ip to access your Mongo database, which I guess is a good practice.

The problem is that Firebase has dynamic ip addresses for its servers, and I saw that I was possible to assign a static address thanks to this procedure : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings

I followed the procedure, creating a new VPC network, then a NAT cloud, router etc... to finally obtain a static IP (which is described in https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/list) used by the router.

I thought I followed every step as asked, but when I add that ip address to MongoDB whitelist, the connection between Firebase Cloud Functions and MongoDB seem to still be blocked.

Anyone already tried that and could help me ?

Comment: When you check the MongoDB access logs (how you do this depends on who is hosting the database), do you see the blocked request coming from the expected static IP address?

Comment: oh great idea thanks, I didn't know we had access to that kind of informations, I'll have to check this out :)